# write.csv is messing header names when writing data frame to disk

Tags: r, csv, export-to-csv

I'm writing to disk a bunch of data frames using write.csv:

```
data_frames <- Filter(function(x) is(x, "data.frame"), mget(ls()))

for (i in 1:length(data_frames)) {

 file_name<- paste0("data/to_save/",names(data_frames[i]),".csv")

 write.csv(data_frames[i], file = file_name, row.names = FALSE, col.names = TRUE)

}
```

The issue is that header is messed adding filename to every colname like this (opened a file with notepad):

```
"April2016_file.customer_id","April2016_file.customerName","April2016_file.customerSurname".......
```

Same behaviour using `write.table`and using `export` script from package `rio`

Required result:

```
"customer_id","customerName","customerSurname"....
```

Comment: For more information either look at the documentation (`?"["`) or see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169456/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to extract the `list` elements  with `[[` as `[` is still a `list` with a single `data.frame`

```
for (i in seq_along(data_frames)) {
  file_name<- paste0("data/to_save/",names(data_frames[i]),".csv")
   write.csv(data_frames[[i]], file = file_name, row.names = FALSE, col.names = TRUE)
}
```

Comment: No completely understood behaviour, but akrun suggestion did the trick. Thanks!!!

Comment: @Forge What happens is when you are a writing a list element, it also has a name which gets appended, while with `[[`, you are extracting the `list` element, so you are avoidng it. i.e. `lst <- setNames(1:3, LETTERS[1:3]); lst[1]` vs `lst[[1]]`

Comment: akrun, in this case I think you could have closed the question with the link I provided since the question shows that OP only requires the correct understanding of the difference between the two extraction functions (which is well explained in the linked Q).. but I didn't since you already answered with a working solution.

Comment: @docendodiscimus  I posted the solution before you commented..   I guess this is in reply to my Possible dupe tag in other post.